# Change views exposed filter format

Tags: views, 8

I am build a JSON export using a View in Drupal 8. Problem is that the parameters for retrieving the json doesn't seem to work as I would want.

In my View I need use two exposed filter criteria to select a date range.  Both fields are Date and Time fields. When clicking on one of the criteria I have created it says:

> **Value type**
>
> A date in any machine readable format. CCYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS is
>   preferred.

I would like this url with this parameter values to work: `http://example.com/api/?start=20161101&end=20161102`

I thought it was working at first, but apparently not when I get my results.

This works:

```
http://example.com/api/?start=2016-12-08%2000%3A00%3A00&end=2016-12-21%2024%3A00%3A00
```

I am trying to have those clean parameters instead. How can I change the filter format to use the `YYYYMMDD` format? I don't want to change my field type because it is storing the time for my events. I want to get the data through only dates.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:
 - [Set the filter granularity](https://www.drupal.org/node/2481343) to "Day"
 - Add a date format "Ymd" admin/config/regional/date-time/formats
 - Add a date type to attach that to...admin/config/regional/date-time
 - OR, just change whatever date type the view is using to use it